# Node.js: how to send HTTPS requests to an app which uses a self-signed certificate

Tags: node.js, post, https, self-signed-certificate

I have **2 Node.js applications accessible via HTTPS**. I'm currently using **self-signed certificates** for those services. Manual access (via a browser or Postman) to those services work as expected (with the usual security warnings about self-signed certificates, etc.).

But as for now, I cannot have one application communicate with the other via HTTPS. Here's my current code:

```
// Request parameters and options
const https = require('https');
const postData = JSON.stringify(myPostData);
const options = {
  hostname: '...',
  port: ...,
  path: '...',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': postData.length,
  },
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
};
let str = '';
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  // Assembling response data...
  res.on('data', chunk => str += chunk );
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Received:', str);
  });
});
// Error handling
req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
// Sending payload and terminating
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

---

**Question**

This works, but only because I use `rejectUnauthorized: false`.

**How can I avoid to use this option?** I see that I can provide a `cert` option (in `https.RequestOptions`), but I'm unsure of how to use it. As I created the self-signed certificate, I possess every pieces of it.

My cert file, named `selfsigned.crt`, looks like this (and has Unix EOL):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MFoXDTI0MTEyNTE3NTczMFowgYcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkZSMQ0wCwYDVQQIDARQQUNB
QGNlbmVhdS5jb20wggIiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4ICDwAwggIKAoICAQCrP3Hy
........... lots of lines ......................................
zI2hWprwsM3PGb0DLCqlotqdoxu59PQRC7aj/yb11HyfyYO9hvFmjGPkmN6T0+r6
VQQGEwJGUjENMAs/Qs7p+B9/+taee8iPWpk=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have tried these solutions:

- indicated the cert string as the `ca` and/or `cert` request options (see their [description](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options)) - I know this is actually taken into account, as if the string is malformed, the error is different (and related to the certificate format)
- indicated the path of the cert to the 'NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS' environment variable, as suggested by [Ashish Modi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59058627/1094673))
- copied the cert file in the /etc/ssl/certs/ (calling application OS is debian) and launched `update-ca-certificates`

All of those solutions change nothing to the outcome:

```
code: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
Error: self signed certificate
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1055:34)
```

As for now, I still don't have a working solution.

***Bonus question!*** I'm very surprised how messy a simple call can look, all chronologically upside-down it gets with the callbacks. Is there a cleaner way to proceed a HTTPS call? => `request-promise` *might be an option, as indicated by **jfriend00***

Comment: *Is there a cleaner way to proceed a HTTPS call?* - Yeah, use the `request-promise` library with promises.  You can also even use `async/await` with the promise if you want.  `https.request()` with plain callbacks is like going down to bare metal when you have much higher level and easier to use options built on top of that.

Comment: That was fast! = ) This library sounds indeed promising, thanks! I'll go to it. I'll have to set-up my certificate with this one too though, but it seems one can use the same agent options, so as soon as I'll know how...

Comment: Yeah, on the cert stuff, I don't know exactly how to do it myself, but conceptually, you want to teach the local client to trust your self-signed CA.  I am curious how one does that so I'm tracking the question hoping someone else can show you the way.

Comment: I'm very surprised how I'm struggling finding documentation about how to deal with self-signed certs. When using it internally (between internal services), I'd have thought it would not be unusual to do so.

Comment: Maybe see the code [in this article](https://community.apigee.com/articles/28041/nodejs-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates.html) under the heading: "Define https Request Program".  There you specify a CA as part of the request.

Comment: Also, read this: [tls.createSecureContext()](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options).  The TLS library in node.js is what `https.request()` and `request()` and `request-promise()` is built on top of.  The operative part of that function is the `ca` option which starts with this description: ***Optionally override the trusted CA certificates***.

Comment: Thank you for the resources. By specifying the ca/cert options, I have some progress now: "error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line". Or is it backward progress? ; ) Actually yes, that happens when I omit the beginning "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" line. So at least, something is taken into account here! ; ) I'll have to see to that tomorrow. Thx again!

Comment: I am facing the same issue and not able to find any working solution on the web. Could you solve this issue? Do you have a working solution somewhere on github?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've migrated to a system using non-self-signed certificates (by using Let's Encrypt free ones).

Answer (score 0):

This option can be set to pass the extra certs

```
process.env["NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS"] = "some/path/to/ssl.crt"
```

This option can completely disable the ssl errors (not recommended)

```
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it didn't work in my case. I've edited my question to reflect my current state of investigation.